# Constraint Issue Unsatisfied MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

i have an array S[1,4,2,3,0] of index[1,2,3,4,5] and an array O[2,1,1,2] of index [1,2,3,4], from these two i have to generat an array SO[2,2,1,1,0] of index [1,2,3,4,5]. When i run with constraint forall(i in 1..5)(SO[i] = O[S[i]]); i get error unsatisfied because of no index 0 for O. Please Help me out with this i am new to minizinc and i dont find sufficient material to help

''''''

```
constraint forall(i in 1..5)(SO[i] = O[S[i]]);`i/p array S[1,4,2,3,0] of index[1,2,3,4,5];
```

Comment: Can you publish the complete MiniZinc model?

Comment: Well, this model in your comment is a quite different from the one you first posted (partially) in your main question. This model do not get the same error what I can see (it seems that's the `all_different` constraint that is the culprit here). Would you please update your question to what you really want to ask?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your model is that `S[5]` is `0` (zero) and there no corresponding `SO[0]`.

I'm not sure if you thought that MiniZinc would automatically yield a `0` if the value of `O[0]` is missing, but MiniZinc requires that you are explicit about the indices in an array when it don't start at 1.

You can fix this by adding an index of 0 (zero) in the `O` array, together with `array1d`:

```
array[1..5] of int: S = [1,4,2,3,0];
array[0..4] of int: O = array1d(0..4,[0,2,1,1,2]);  # <---

array[1..5] of var 0..2: SO;

solve satisfy;

constraint forall(i in 1..5) (
                          SO[i] = O[S[i]]
                          );
```

The result is:

```
SO = array1d(1..5 ,[2, 2, 1, 1, 0]);
```